# Making an iframe with a "dynamic" url

Tags: javascript, url, iframe, src

I am just getting started with coding and I have had a basic introduction to HTML and CSS and Javascript. 
I would like to create a page with an iframe that has some "dynamic" url of the source. 
So, instead of defining the source with some specific url, I want to the url from the source from a string that I would fill in a form.

Would this be possible? If so, do you have any advice?

I am just doing this for my own amusement as I am really curious about this kind of stuff.

If you don't want to give me the answer straight away just give me some links on where to find useful info.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: please read [How to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) , since we can't help you until you tried something first .

Comment: Hello. I have read the How to ask section. 
What I would like to know is how to change the attribute of the iframe element, in this case, the attribute to change would be the src URL.

Answer (score 2):

Give the following JavaScript a try to change the source of your iframe.

```
document.getElementById('id_of_iframe').src = "https://www.google.com";
```

For the input you can use the jQuery .val() method, as described [here](http://api.jquery.com/val/).
Combine this information and create something yourself :)

Comment: Thank you so much. it works. This was exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: Good to hear, hope you learned a lot of new things. Can you please upvote and accept my answer? Thank you.